# need help on perl program

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp, ini

as of now I have a new computer and am still working on installing perl I need some one to test for me what the output of my program is (if it even works) if not please tell me what I can do to fix it (the Config::INI::Reader is a cpan class so you might want to get it if you don't have it

perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::Socket;
use Config::INI::Reader;

my $file = "ServerSettings.ini";
my $ini = Config::INI::Reader->read_file($file);
my $server_info = $ini->{'ServerInfo'};
my $version = $ini->{'Version'};
my $host = $server_info->{'address'};
my $port = $server_info->{port};
my $server = new IO::Socket::INET(Proto=>'tcp',PeerAddr=>$host,PeerPort=>$port);

die "Connection Failed \n" unless $server;

print "Connection Established \n";
print "James Server" . $version->{ver} . "\n";
print "Hello From James Server";
```

here is the ini:

```
[ServerSettings]
port=1234
address"localhost"

[Version]
ver="1.0.3"
```

Comment: shouldn't it be address= in the ini file?

Comment: Shouldn't `server_info` be `$server_info`? A rather good idea when posting code that doesn't work is to also post the error messages. To not do so is rather strange. It's like going to the doctor and saying "So, there's something wrong. Guess what it is?"

Comment: "...I need some one to test for me..." is not a very useful question, nor has it shown that you've done much to figure out the problem on your own.  Consider next time adding what you've tried and what errors you have after you get your environment set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use warnings;
use strict;
use Config::INI::Reader;

my $file = "/tmp/l.ini";
my $ini = Config::INI::Reader->read_file($file);
my $server_info = $ini->{ServerSettings};
my $version = $ini->{Version};

my $host = $server_info->{address};
my $port = $server_info->{port};
my $ver = $version->{ver};

print $host;
print $port;
print $ver;
```

You have a typo in ini file, missing a `=`

```
[ServerSettings]
port=1234
address="localhost"

[Version]
ver="1.0.3"
```

Comment: Random `-l` switch in the shebang?

Comment: What do you mean by random ? It's there to do the same as `say` : print newlines. Need to `chmod +x script.pl; ./script.pl` to work properly...

Comment: By random I mean that it is there for seemingly no reason. I am sure it does something, but perhaps you should mention what your intent with it is. Or at the very least emphasize that it is there. If all you want is for your code to add newlines to print, perhaps you should consider using `use feature 'say'` instead. Or set `$\ ` to `"\n"`. Using a switch in the shebang is the sort of behaviour that will cause confusion later on when someone doesn't understand why your script auto-chomps its input.

Comment: _There's more than one way to do it_ =) This is mine sometimes...

Comment: I know, and I have started to do it myself in one-liners. For some reason it is much easier to type `perl -lwe` than it is to type `perl -wE`. Besides, I always found myself typing `print` instead of say anyway. However, using a switch in the shebang is perhaps not the best thing for a script, for the reasons I mentioned above.